# In a .NET web-application, what is the difference between the following?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, ashx

I'm mainly trying to understand this. What is the purpose for all of these classes with similar names in a .NET application ?

Also, in which of these will I see more implementation-details?.
I assume the .ASPX one is the actual web site?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.aspx` file contains the markup of the page, i.e. HTML code with server tags intermixed.

The `.aspx.cs` file is the code behind file, that contains the C# code for the page class.

The `.aspx.designer.cs` file contains the automatically generated C# code that declares the controls in the markup file as properties in the page class, so that you can easily access them.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same class. It is splitted just for your comfort.
You might want to have a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178138(v=vs.100).aspx
Or read some other papers about web forms. But actually you may put all these together in the same file.
So all the code staff, like event handlers should be in the PageName.aspx.cs file. in the PageName.aspx you should have html markup. And probably you won't be interested much in generated file as it contains stuff that was generated for you, so you will loose all your code in this file on next regeneration.